# Installing libvala >= 0.12 on OS X

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to build MonoDevelop from the source linked to on [their website](http://monodevelop.com/Download) on a system running OS X 10.8.5. I've run `git submodule init` and `update`, but `libvala-0.12` can't be found. I've tried MacPorts and Brew, but neither have `libvala` available. Turning to the Internet, the only package I've found with `libvala` is a Debian package, and I don't know of any way to install those on an OS X system.

Has anyone else here had this issue? If so, what's a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libvala-0.12` is not for Mac.

Run the configure command as shown below instead:

`./configure --profile=mac`

Comment: Can you expound upon this? I've come across several open source projects that won't compile, stating a missing `libvala` package as the cause. Many of them don't have a "profile" argument.